# How to match exact domain link in text with regex like "telegram.org" or etc but not "telegram.org/" subcategories

Tags: php, regex

i use preg_match() function in php to find match inside string.

```
**$var="you can find in telegram.org/";
if(preg_match("(?=(?!(telegram\.org).*)",&var)>0)
{
   echo "ok";
}else{
 echo "fault";
}**
```

i want to print fault.

Comment: Please note that `telegram.org` is _not_ a URL! It is a domain name.

Comment: sorry yes you're correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
if (preg_match('~^(?!.*telegram\.org/).*telegram\.org~', $var)) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/biEOMX/2).

This pattern will match any string containing `telegram.org` but not `telegram.org/`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*telegram\.org/)` - no `telegram.org/` anywhere in the string is allowed
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `telegram\.org` - a `telegram.org` substring.

**NOTE** You need a regex if you want to match the `telegram.org` as a whole word:

```
'~^(?!.*\btelegram\.org/).*\btelegram\.org\b~'
```

Check the `\b`, word boundary. Else, you might consider other, non-regex ways to match the string. Like [the one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418838/3832970), but - perhaps, better - [with `stripos`](https://ideone.com/IOokbv), for a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: what is the meaning of ~?

Comment: @MohammadrezaTaheri It is a regex delimiter so that a `/` could be used in the pattern in an unescaped form. If I used `/`, I'd have to write `\/`. Am I right about your intentions? Match any string containing `telegram.org` but not `telegram.org/`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using regex for this.  `strpos()` is fast and can do this task well.

Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c457dc8de5bcb856546a7e73167515c13f318df5) that only needs to call `strpos()` twice:

```
$vars=["you can find in telegram.org/","you can find in telegram.org","telegram.org here"];
$find='telegram.org';
foreach($vars as $var){
    if(strpos($var,$find)!==false && strpos($var,$find.'/')===false){
        echo "$find found without /\n";
    }else{
        echo "$find failed\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
telegram.org failed
telegram.org found without /
telegram.org found without /
```

---

If you are set on regex, I think `~telegram\.org(?!/)~` does the job well enough.  Just check for the string and see that it is not immediately followed by a `/`.

Comment: The `telegram\.org(?!/)` won't do the job, because it will match a `telegram.org telegram.org/` string.

Comment: Fair enough, I figured there was a good reason you didn't post that pattern.  Yes, my regex pattern will give unintended results if both passing and failing substrings are in the string.  It come down to whether there is a possibility of multiple substrings in the string.